# How to execute a function every time the app enters a given route in ember-js

Tags: ember.js

Suppose I have got a given ember application

`App = Ember.Application.create()`

A router

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("posts", function() {
    this.resource("post", {
      path: "/:post_id"
    })
  });
});
```

How do I execute a function each time whenever the application enters a given /:post_id ?

Comment: I tried doing that.It does not work as expected.Example when switching between post 1 and post 2 ... the activate function should be called again.here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iqolak/17/edit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement `App.PostRoute` to specify your custom behavior for your `post` route. If you don't, Ember will create this class behind the scenes.

The `activate` hook is called on the route every time the route is activated.

Example:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the hooks in the Router request lifecycle here: http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/02/08/router-request-lifecycle/

Comment: You should use `setupController()`. The `model()` hook isn't always called, i.e. when you are transitioning to a route using a `{{linkTo}}` link.

Comment: Yes.. agreed... I'm editing the answer to only point to blog post listing hooks